# Why do styled-components keep old classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I recently tried to switch from Less to `styled-components`. It looks like a new class is appended in my document head every time a styled component is re-rendered.

So, for example, with this code :

```js
const Loop = () => {
  const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(100);
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => setOpacity(opacity => opacity - 1), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);
  return <Test opacity={opacity} />;
};

const Test = styled.div`
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: black;
  opacity: ${props => props.opacity / 100};
`;

render(<Loop />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

The css content keeps growing every second :

[image]

In my real project, I have big CSS classes that need to update frequently, and the web app needs to stay open for a long time in the browser, so this might be a deal-breaker.
Am I doing something wrong or is this normal ? I couldn't find anything in the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [dynamic class](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#why-do-my-dom-nodes-have-two-classes) generated from `styled-components`, and
[identical css string should generate the same class](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1299#issuecomment-342653251). (But different classes will be generated when reopening the app)

That is, when the component is re-rendered again, classes should be reused for it, and no additional classes will be generated.

In [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-dynamic-class-jfete), 10 classes will be generated and reused.